# easy_install matplotlib updates on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, easy-install

I'm currently using matplotlib 1.0.1, running with Python 2.7.1, but like to update it to at least 1.1.0. However, when I tried downloading matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/,

the subsequent installation states "matplotlib 1.1.0 can't be installed on this disk. matplotlib requires System Python 2.7 to install."

Alternatively, I tried $easy_install matplotlib in the terminal and got the following output:

> install_dir
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
>   Searching for matplotlib Best match: matplotlib 1.0.1 Adding
>   matplotlib 1.0.1 to easy-install.pth file
>
> Using
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   Processing dependencies for matplotlib Finished processing
>   dependencies for matplotlib

And $easy_install upgrade matplotlib got the following errors:

> BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
>               matplotlib: 1.1.0
>                   python: 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (32-bit)| (r271:86832, Dec  3 2010,
>                           15:41:32)  [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)]
>                 platform: darwin
>
> REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
>                    numpy: 1.5.1
>                freetype2: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
>                           * WARNING: Could not find 'freetype2' headers in any
>                           * of '.', './freetype2'.
>
> OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
>                   libpng: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
>                           * Could not find 'libpng' headers in any of '.'
>                  Tkinter: Tkinter: 81008, Tk: 8.4, Tcl: 8.4
>                     Gtk+: no
>                           * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
>                           * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
>          Mac OS X native: yes
>                       Qt: no
>                      Qt4: no
>                    Cairo: no
>
> OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
>                 datetime: present, version unknown
>                 dateutil: 1.5
>                     pytz: 2010o
>
> OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
>                   dvipng: 1.13
>              ghostscript: 8.71
>                    latex: 3.1415926
>
> [Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]
>   ============================================================================ pymods ['pylab'] packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends',
>   'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor', 'matplotlib.projections',
>   'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units',
>   'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d',
>   'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1',
>   'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext', 'matplotlib.tri',
>   'matplotlib.delaunay'] warning: no files found matching 'KNOWN_BUGS'
>   warning: no files found matching 'INTERACTIVE' warning: no files found
>   matching 'MANIFEST' warning: no files found matching '**init**.py'
>   warning: no files found matching 'examples/data/*' warning: no files
>   found matching 'lib/mpl_toolkits' warning: no files found matching
>   'LICENSE*' under directory 'license' In file included from
>   src/ft2font.h:16,
>                    from src/ft2font.cpp:3: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/include/ft2build.h:56:38:
>   error: freetype/config/ftheader.h: No such file or directory In file
>   included from src/ft2font.cpp:3: src/ft2font.h:17:10: error: #include
>   expects "FILENAME" or  src/ft2font.h:18:10: error: #include
>   expects "FILENAME" or  src/ft2font.h:19:10: error: #include
>   expects "FILENAME" or  src/ft2font.h:20:10: error: #include
>   expects "FILENAME" or  src/ft2font.h:21:10: error: #include
>   expects "FILENAME" or  In file included from
>   src/ft2font.cpp:3: src/ft2font.h:35: error: ‘FT_Bitmap’ has not been
>   declared src/ft2font.h:35: error: ‘FT_Int’ has not been declared
>   src/ft2font.h:35: error: ‘FT_Int’ has not been declared
>   src/ft2font.h:91: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
>   src/ft2font.h:91: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘FT_Face’ with
>   no type src/ft2font.h:138: error: ‘FT_Face’ does not name a type
>   src/ft2font.h:139: error: ‘FT_Matrix’ does not name a type
>   src/ft2font.h:140: error: ‘FT_Vector’ does not name a type
>   src/ft2font.h:141: error: ‘FT_Error’ does not name a type
>   src/ft2font.h:142: error: ‘FT_Glyph’ was not declared in this scope
>   src/ft2font.h:142: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>   src/ft2font.h:142: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>   src/ft2font.h:143: error: ‘FT_Vector’ was not declared in this scope
>   src/ft2font.h:143: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>   src/ft2font.h:143: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>   src/ft2font.h:149: error: ‘FT_BBox’ does not name a type
>   src/ft2font.cpp:51: error: ‘FT_Library’ does not name a type
>   src/ft2font.cpp:114: error: variable or field ‘draw_bitmap’ declared
>   void src/ft2font.cpp:114: error: ‘FT_Bitmap’ was not declared in this
>   scope src/ft2font.cpp:114: error: ‘bitmap’ was not declared in this
>   scope src/ft2font.cpp:115: error: ‘FT_Int’ was not declared in this
>   scope src/ft2font.cpp:116: error: ‘FT_Int’ was not declared in this
>   scope error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with
>   exit status 1

Sorry if this problem is too elementary, but I just can't figure out where the error might be. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Although you can use a package manager like MacPorts or homebrew to install matplotlib on OS X, if you are interested in a method that uses only the XCode-provided freetype and libpng libraries, see my answer to a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10843478/781673).

Answer (score 0):

Try using pypi!

There is already matplotlib 1.1
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.1.0