# Python - Installing matplotlib in Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I've been having trouble installing matplotlib. I'm getting a similar error to many other topics, but none of those solutions have been working for me. I have tried installing matplotlib via pip and via git and I receive the same error every time I would very much appreciate help.

```
In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
src/ft2font.h:16:22: error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
src/ft2font.h:17:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
src/ft2font.h:18:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
src/ft2font.h:19:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
src/ft2font.h:20:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
src/ft2font.h:21:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
src/ft2font.h:34: error: 'FT_Bitmap' has not been declared
src/ft2font.h:34: error: 'FT_Int' has not been declared
src/ft2font.h:34: error: 'FT_Int' has not been declared
src/ft2font.h:86: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
src/ft2font.h:86: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'FT_Face' with no type
src/ft2font.h:132: error: 'FT_Face' does not name a type
src/ft2font.h:133: error: 'FT_Matrix' does not name a type
src/ft2font.h:134: error: 'FT_Vector' does not name a type
src/ft2font.h:135: error: 'FT_Error' does not name a type
src/ft2font.h:136: error: 'FT_Glyph' was not declared in this scope
src/ft2font.h:136: error: template argument 1 is invalid
src/ft2font.h:136: error: template argument 2 is invalid
src/ft2font.h:137: error: 'FT_Vector' was not declared in this scope
src/ft2font.h:137: error: template argument 1 is invalid
src/ft2font.h:137: error: template argument 2 is invalid
src/ft2font.h:143: error: 'FT_BBox' does not name a type
src/ft2font.cpp:41: error: 'FT_Library' does not name a type
src/ft2font.cpp:106: error: variable or field 'draw_bitmap' declared void
src/ft2font.cpp:106: error: 'FT_Bitmap' was not declared in this scope
src/ft2font.cpp:106: error: 'bitmap' was not declared in this scope
src/ft2font.cpp:107: error: 'FT_Int' was not declared in this scope
src/ft2font.cpp:108: error: 'FT_Int' was not declared in this scope
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1532: warning: 'int _import_array()' defined but not used
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Looks like you're running into problems with `freetype2`. Two ways around it are to install [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and install `python` that way, then do `brew install freetype` and install matplotlib with that python. The alternative is to install [Quartz X11](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki), which will give you much newer and updated freetype libs.

Comment: Although you can use a package manager like MacPorts or homebrew to install matplotlib on OS X, if you are interested in a method that uses only the XCode-provided freetype and libpng libraries, see my answer to a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10843478/781673).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.  I use brew.  I fixed this by doing

```
brew install freetype
brew link freetype
brew install libpng
brew link libpng
brew install matplotlib
```

By default, brew leaves your system versions of freetype and libpng active, which is why you need to do "brew link" as well.  Hope that helps.

Update: I would now recommend using the free version of Anaconda Python.  Then this is trivial.

Comment: Looks like newer versions of Homebrew require using `--force` for linking, i.e. `brew link --force freetype` etc. Other than that, these steps worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend to go through a package manager instead of trying to compile source code by yourself. This is much more efficient.

An nice alternative to homebrew is the famous [MacPorts](http://macports.org) package manager:

```
sudo port install py27-matplotlib
```

I used [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org), the third major package manager for OS X, in the past, and I find MacPorts significantly more robust and up-to-date.

There are many comparisons between the OS X package managers on the web (including some [nice ones](http://terrychay.com/article/macports-vs-homebrew.shtml)), so that you can better decide which manager to commit to.

Answer (score 1):

You can doit in easy way with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install python
$ brew install gfortran
$ brew install pkg-config
$ easy_install pip
$ pip install numpy
$ cd $HOME
$ git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
$ cd matplotlib
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: if i run python setup.py build or python setup.py install it gives the above message still