# Python Mac OSX matplotlib Error _png.so Version

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm trying to use matplotlib with Python 2.7.3 on MacOSX (10.8.3) but I'm getting the following error when I attempt to import matplotlib.figure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.figure
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 32, in <module>
    from matplotlib.image import FigureImage
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _png.so requires version 27.0.0 or later, but libpng15.15.dylib provides version 20.0.0
```

I attempted using solutions from a few different sources over the past week or so, most recently this one:

[Python - Installing matplotlib in Mac OSX Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508360/python-installing-matplotlib-in-mac-osx-snow-leopard)

And I still get the same error. I'm pretty confused as to why this error is occurring and how to fix it...

Any potential solutions?

Comment: You need to update the version `libpng` on your system.  The issue is with the external libraries, not with `matplotlib`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363557/matplotlib-install-failure-on-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion that helpful?