# Python/Eclipse can't import MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to install MatPlotLib for Python (OS X) using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092994/unable-to-install-matplotlib-on-mac-os-x). The guide seems to work fine: in fact if I open a terminal and I start a Python session, the command
`import matplotlib` works. But if I try to do the same with Eclipse, it doesn't work and the IDE can't resolve the import.

I'm a newbie in Python programming, so if you have any advice I'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH is my guess. Work out how to set the pythonpath for the environment in eclipse and ensure it includes whereever matplotlib resides.