# Error installing Python Image Library using pip on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: python, macos, pip

I want to install PIL on Mavericks using pip but get this error.

```
_imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found
#include <freetype/fterrors.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

My Command Line Tools are installed and up to date and every hint I found didn't help.
How can I get this to compile?

EDIT: I just checked, freetype is also already installed via homebrew

Comment: You need `freetype` headers.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that ;) Also just found a way to solve this.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Instead of symlinking to a specific version of freetype2, do this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

This saves you the trouble of recreating the symlink whenever you upgrade freetype2.

Comment: after using `sudo easy_install PIL`, I come across this issue, your solution works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: this fixed the issue on Yosemite too

Comment: I had freetype2 already linked, it may be best to link the original which was at /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.5/include/freetype2

Comment: @Salyangoz: /usr/local/include/freetype2 is a symlink to /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.5/include/freetype2 (it's created by Homebrew). Using this instead of the actual path, has the advantage when doing an upgrade that it will still work.

Comment: Freetype2 was not installed on my machine running El Capitan, so I had to run `brew install freetype` before making this symlink

Comment: I had to do `sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/freetype2 /opt/local/include/freetype` in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 31):

With macports, the solution that worked for me:

```
sudo port install freetype
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/freetype2 /opt/local/include/freetype
```

And then re-run the PIL build process.

Comment: this worked for me when i upgraded to maverick thanks

Comment: worked for me on yosemite while upgrading to cocos2dx v3.3 from 2.2

Answer (score 27):

I've solved this problem with this symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.1/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

I have freetype already installed via homebrew too.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by a change in the headers of freetype >= 2.1.5. PIL is not using the correct documented way to include the freetype headers, which causes the build to fail now that freetype finally removed the long-deprecated way of including the headers. This problem is documented right at the top of http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html:

> NOTE: Starting with FreeType 2.1.6, the old header file inclusion scheme is no longer supported. This means that you now get an error if you do something like the following:
>
> #include <freetype/freetype.h>
> #include <freetype/ftglyph.h>

Please take this problem upstream to the developers of PIL and advise them to use the documented way of including freetype headers:

`#include <ft2build.h>`
`#include FT_ERRORS_H`

Answer (score 4):

After many attempts, I solved this problem compiling the PIL without freetype support. To do that, I simply unlinked from my $PATH using `brew unlink freetype` and then, `pip install PIL==1.1.7`.

Comment: what is freetype, anyway? :)

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this using the steps described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10843478/1188527) Stackoverflow answer.
Seems this is Xcode's fault for installing freetype in strange locations.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Pillow](http://python-pillow.github.com) where this issue is fixed "for real":

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commit/c6040f618d8f2706a7b46d1cdf37d1a587f9701f

And where you can report issues and see them addressed in a timely fashion:

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues

Answer (score 2):

In my OSx, I found the `.h` file in `/opt/local/include/freetype2` direcoty. So, I type

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/freetype2/ /usr/local/include/freetype
```

it works

Maybe the best way is to add `/opt/local/include` to your clang's include path.

Answer (score 1):

osx yosemite, this worked for me:

(virtualenv)

```
$ ln -s /opt/local/include/freetype2/ /usr/local/include/freetype2
$ pip install pil==1.1.7 --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil
```

Comment: Ran the first line only, then this worked for me on Yosemite. Was able to `pip install PIL`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Arch Linux and had this issue.  In my case had to manually download and unpack the zip file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1#downloads .  I then edited the file `_imagingft.c` to change the include path from `freetype/fterrors.h` to `fterrors.h` as there was no `freetype` subdirectory of `/usr/include/freetype2` where `fterrors.h` was located.  Finally `python setup.py install` worked fine.

Edit:  I should mention this was the solution for installing Pillow, not PIL, but Pillow is just a fork of PIL and it may still be applicable to others with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for answers like I was after reading this and other googling, you may be interested to see this:

Warning

Pillow >= 2.1.0 no longer supports “import _imaging”. Please use “from PIL.Image import core as _imaging” instead.

from [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

By the time you read this, the page will probably have changed, but the text will be still here at least.