# Cannot install Command Line Developer Tools on OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos

When I run `xcode-select --install` in the Terminal, I get the prompt to install the Developer Tools as desired (and as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools?lq=1)). But when I run the installation, the process stops at around 50% with a message along the lines of:

> Could not install the software because the update server cannot be reached.

My internet connection works fine and I do not think that Apple's servers can be down for more than a couple of hours so I looked at the Console. This is what I found there:

> 23.02.14 23:25:38,513 mds[63]: (Normal) Volume: volume:0x7fdb79016000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
>
> 23.02.14 23:25:38,538 fseventsd[73]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
>
> 23.02.14 23:25:38,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s3

Next I tried to install the Developer Tools from http://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and the installer said the installation was successful. Except that the Developer Tools still don't work.

```
xcode-select -p
```

returns

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

What is the issue here?

**UPDATE**

It looks like the .dmg install from http://developer.apple.com/downloads/ was actually successful. The reason I wanted to install the Deveolper Tools in the first place was because I wanted to install the Python Imaging Library with PIP but failed and read somewhere that this was due to the lack of the Command Line Developer Tools. I found a solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325473/error-installing-python-image-library-using-pip-on-mac-os-x-10-9). The question of my thread is not really resolved though (why the misleading message when I try to install the Developer Tools?) which is why I do not mark the question as answered for now.