# Installing PIL on OS X 10.9 - Clang throwing 12 errors

Tags: macos, clang, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install PIL using `pip` on OS X 10.9, but have run into issues similar to [this person's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532125/cant-install-pil-after-mac-os-x-10-9), [this one's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334776/installing-pillow-pil-on-mavericks), [this one's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa), and [this one's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325473/error-installing-python-image-library-using-pip-on-mac-os-x-10-9). I've summarily tried every one of the solutions mentioned in answers to those questions, and several combinations of them, but I still get ***12 errors*** from Clang:

```
In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:75:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_def.h:46:16: error: redefinition of '_types_fd_set'

typedef struct fd_set {

               ^

/opt/local/arm-none-eabi/include/sys/types.h:235:16: note: expanded from macro 'fd_set'

#define fd_set _types_fd_set

               ^

/opt/local/arm-none-eabi/include/sys/types.h:231:16: note: previous definition is here

typedef struct _types_fd_set {

               ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:75:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_fd_def.h:48:3: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct _types_fd_set' (aka '_types_fd_set') vs 'struct _types_fd_set')

} fd_set;

  ^

/opt/local/arm-none-eabi/include/sys/types.h:235:16: note: expanded from macro 'fd_set'

#define fd_set _types_fd_set

               ^

/opt/local/arm-none-eabi/include/sys/types.h:233:3: note: previous definition is here

} _types_fd_set;

  ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:76:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_timespec.h:30:1: error: redefinition of 'timespec'

_STRUCT_TIMESPEC

^

/usr/include/sys/_types/_timespec.h:29:33: note: expanded from macro '_STRUCT_TIMESPEC'

#define _STRUCT_TIMESPEC        struct timespec

                                       ^

/opt/local/arm-none-eabi/include/sys/types.h:115:8: note: previous definition is here

struct timespec {

       ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:76:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_timespec.h:32:2: error: unknown type name '__darwin_time_t'

        __darwin_time_t tv_sec;

        ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:77:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_timeval.h:30:1: error: redefinition of 'timeval'

_STRUCT_TIMEVAL

^

/usr/include/sys/_types/_timeval.h:29:33: note: expanded from macro '_STRUCT_TIMEVAL'

#define _STRUCT_TIMEVAL         struct timeval

                                       ^

/opt/local/arm-none-eabi/include/sys/time.h:17:8: note: previous definition is here

struct timeval {

       ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:77:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_timeval.h:32:2: error: unknown type name '__darwin_time_t'

        __darwin_time_t         tv_sec;         /* seconds */

        ^

/usr/include/sys/_types/_timeval.h:33:2: error: unknown type name '__darwin_suseconds_t'

        __darwin_suseconds_t    tv_usec;        /* and microseconds */

        ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:84:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_time_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_time_t'

typedef __darwin_time_t         time_t;

        ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:85:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_suseconds_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_suseconds_t'

typedef __darwin_suseconds_t    suseconds_t;

        ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:86:

/usr/include/sys/_types/_sigset_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_sigset_t'

typedef __darwin_sigset_t               sigset_t;

        ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

/usr/include/sys/select.h:118:3: error: expected function body after function declarator

                __DARWIN_EXTSN_C(pselect)

                ^

In file included from _imaging.c:76:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:351:

In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:129:

/usr/include/sys/_select.h:42:3: error: expected function body after function declarator

                __DARWIN_EXTSN_C(select)

                ^

12 errors generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm using `pip` 1.4.1, `python` 2.7.5, and `clang` 3.4 with `llvm` 5.1.

Is there anything not mentioned in those answers that I could try? Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing PIL with this command:

`ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pil`

#### More info:

I had the exact same error as some of the issues you linked (particularly the first [this one's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334776/installing-pillow-pil-on-mavericks)). This solution worked for me.

I learned that the compiler that comes with Xcode 5.1 treats unknown passed parameters as errors.

This command tells it to ignore those "errors" while installing PIL.

source: http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html

Comment: I just tried running `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install --allow-all-external  pil --allow-unverified pil` (as `pip` wouldn't allow me to install without those flags), but still, 1 warning, 12 errors. Same dump as in my original question.

Comment: That's too bad – Our configurations look similar, but we have different problems. I'll let you know if I find anything else that might help.

Comment: I'm also still looking, and I'll post an update if anything comes up.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you guys found a solution? thanks