# Can't install Plone 4.2 on Manjaro 0.8.9 (Arch x64)

Tags: plone

I need to install Plone 4.2 on my ManjaroLinux 0.8.9.
Unfortunately, I can't use a newer version of Plone , so I don't know, whether a newer version will install better.

So I downloaded the UnifiedInstaller for Plone 4.2, extracted the archive and tried to install it using the following command:

```
sudo ./install.sh standalone
```

I got the following output:

```
Installing Plone 4.2 at /usr/local/Plone

User 'plone' already exists. No need to create it.
Skipping libjpeg build
Skipping readline build
Installing Python-2.7.3. This takes a while...
Installing distribute...
Warning: This Python does not have readline support.
It may still be usable for Zope, but interacting directly with Python will be painful.

Python build looks OK.
Unpacking buildout cache to /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache
Compiling .py files in egg cache
Copying Plone-docs
Generating random password ...
Your platform's xml2/xslt are up-to-date. No need to build them.
Copying buildout skeleton
Fixing up bin/buildout
Skipping static libxml2/libxslt build.
Building Zope/Plone; this takes a while...
Buildout returned an error code: 1; Aborting.
Buildout failed. Unable to continue

Installation has failed.
See the detailed installation log at /home/maphardam/Downloads/Plone-4.2-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
to determine the cause.
```

As the install.log is pretty big (>600kB), I hope the error message and the end will suffice...

```
_imagingft.c:73:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory
 #include <freetype/fterrors.h>

compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
An error occured when trying to install Pillow 1.7.7. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'Pillow==1.7.7'.
Error: Couldn't install: Pillow 1.7.7
```

I you need the whole log file, I will try to upload it :)

So it seems that the installer misses freetype. A short request with pacman results in the fact, that I already use freetype 2.5.3-2.

What am I doing wrong/ what do i have to do to get Plone running?

Cheers,
Maphardam

EDIT: Topic solved. I fixed it by linking freetype2 to freetype:
    ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype

Comment: Don't know if applicable to your environment, but check this response for MacOs users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325473/error-installing-python-image-library-using-pip-on-mac-os-x-10-9

It's about doing a symlink from new to old-style freetype version.

Comment: You Sir saved my day! Thanks a lot! I haven't thought about linking so far! Now Plone was installed successfully :)